# p4 reconcile marking an existing files as opened for add instead of opened for edit

Tags: perforce

I have a task of migrating a git repository to P4. Due to what needs to be done in the migration process, I can't use any of the existing tools.

The basic idea is quite simple:

1. Pull a commit from git
2. Run P4 reconcile over modified files
3. Submit changelist to P4

It works for the first commit which exclusively adds files to the repo. However, it breaks when I try to process a commit which introduces changes to already existing files.

For some reason, "p4 reconcile" decides to mark these files as "opened for add" instead of "opened for edit". Once I try to submit, I get an error due to trying to add an already added files.

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p4 reconcile` reconciles the state of the workspace relative to what you last synced from the depot.  This is to allow you to resolve changes in your workspace against revisions that might have been submitted to the depot since you synced.

If `reconcile` is opening everything for add, I'd assume you're starting with an empty (unsynced) workspace every time; every file added to an empty workspace is going to be a candidate for "add" since it's not based on an existing revision that was synced from the depot.

The ideal solution would be to reuse the same workspace for each successive commit so that reconcile works as normal, i.e. with the newly updated workspace files compared to the "had" revisions from the depot, and differing files opened for edit at those revisions.

A less-ideal (IMO) solution if you *can't* reuse the same workspace would be to `p4 sync -k`, which tells the server "just assume I have the latest files", and then reconcile using that as the basis.  A problem with this approach is that if other changes are being submitted to the depot, you won't even get any warning before they're overwritten (because you told the server to assume that you already accounted for them); a somewhat lesser problem is that recreating the workspace for every commit and doing `sync -k` adds unnecessary overhead that you could avoid by reusing the existing workspace.

If you are reusing the same workspace but reconcile still opens everything for add, something unusual is going on -- there are a lot of possibilities, but I'd start debugging by inspecting the state of the workspace in between commits (e.g. run `p4 have` after you submit; you should see all the files you just submitted), and look carefully at the result of `reconcile` relative to that state.

Comment: I haven't given enough information for anyone to figure out what the problem was, but when I read your answer I realized what I was doing wrong. Basically, I didn't sync the workspace to the revision of files that I expected them to be at.

Comment: If you used the same workspace to submit the previous commit, it should already be synced to the submitted files, which is why I suggest using the same workspace to submit each successive commit.

Comment: ah, I see -- the one missing thing is that you're doing an obliterate to start over, but you aren't starting over from scratch, so the *initial* changelist isn't in the workspace after the obliterate.

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing a script that needs to migrate from Git to P4. This meant I had to rerun the script over and over, fixing issues as they poped up. In order to not make a mess of history, I did the following:

1. Obliterated all the changelists other than the initial one.
2. Deleted all of the changelist.
3. Rollbacked TFS repository to initial commit to match the state of P4 server.
4. I even set the changelist number to the number of initial changelist (I think it's fine here, but not something I would do on a production server).

And then I tried again.

What I haven't done is synced the workspace to the initial changelist. This is what confused the reconcile command and created a phantom add. Once I added the sync step to the process, it started working as expected.

Comment: When you obliterate, use the `-h` flag to leave the old have records; that way when you sync, it'll automatically clean up the files that you synced which no longer exist in the depot.  (It also makes obliterate faster!)